# Get Total Time from a ListBox Column Display per ComboBox Change

Tags: excel, vba, time, sum, listbox

I have here a snippet of code for ComboBox4 change event. As you can see in the data below (excel image form), there’s a column for Time which has my preferred format of “hh:mm:ss”. I am trying to get the sum of the time column in ListBox (result shown in Label1 of the Form). The result below is not getting the correct sum.

**Form**

[image: Form]

**Excel Sheet Image** (blanks have purpose)
[image: Sheet Image]

Here is the raw data of the image above:

```
Col. A         Col. B      Col. E       Col. G    Col. J           Col. L
YEAR      || NAME   || Total Time   || COLOR    || MONTH        || SHAPE
2023      || LINA   || 0:00:15      || GREEN    || AUGUST       || HEART
2023      || LINA   || 0:00:07      || GREEN    || SEPTEMBER    || CIRCLE
2024      || GARY   || 0:00:01      || GREEN    || SEPTEMBER    || DIAMOND
2024      || GARY   || 0:00:02      || GREEN    || SEPTEMBER    || RECTANGLE
2024      || GARY   || 0:00:15      || RED      || AUGUST       || OVAL
2023      || GARY   || 0:00:07      || RED      || AUGUST       || RECTANGLE
2023      || GARY   || 0:00:01      || GREEN    || AUGUST       || SQUARE
2024      || GARY   || 0:00:02      || GREEN    || SEPTEMBER    || STAR
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:15      || RED      || AUGUST       || HEART
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:07      || RED      || SEPTEMBER    || CIRCLE
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:01      || RED      || SEPTEMBER    || DIAMOND
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:02      || YELLOW   || SEPTEMBER    || OVAL
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:15      || YELLOW   || OCTOBER      || RECTANGLE
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:07      || YELLOW   || OCTOBER      || CIRCLE
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:01      || YELLOW   || OCTOBER      || SQUARE
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:02      || YELLOW   || OCTOBER      || STAR
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:15      || YELLOW   || OCTOBER      || STAR
2024      || TOM    || 0:00:07      || BLUE     || OCTOBER      || SQUARE
```

**Here is the ComboBox4 code:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    If Not ComboBox4.Value = "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, count As Long, K As Long
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim countT As Date 'declared the variable here
        
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        arrData = rng.Value
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng.Columns(1), CStr(ComboBox2.Value), rng.Columns(2), ComboBox1.Value, rng.Columns(7), ComboBox3.Value, rng.Columns(10), ComboBox4.Value)
        ReDim arrList(1 To count + 1, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrList(1, j) = arrData(1, j) 'header
        Next
        K = 1
                
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value And arrData(i, 1) = CStr(ComboBox2.Value) _
                And arrData(i, 7) = ComboBox3.Value And arrData(i, 10) = ComboBox4.Value Then
                K = K + 1
                
                countT = 0
                
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                
                    countT = countT + arrData(i, 5) 'trying to get their total sum
                    
                    arrList(K, 5) = Format(arrData(i, 5), "hh:mm:ss")
                Next
                Label1.Caption = Format(CDate(countT), "hh:mm:ss") 'show total sum in this label in the form of hh:mm:ss
            End If
        Next
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "0,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = arrList
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)` should be eliminated from the nested For loop.
- Initialize `countT` before entering the For loop, and update `label1` after exiting the loop.

If you are curious about how the time `0:03:00` is determined, here is the explanation with your code:

- The variable countT is initialized, and the label is updated within the outer nested loop (for i loop).
- The value displayed on the label corresponds to the last value that meets the if condition, which is "0:0:15."
- The inner loop (for j loop) runs 12 times (UBound(arrData,2) is 12), so countT accumulates to 180 seconds (12 * 15), which is equivalent to "0:03:00"

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    If Not ComboBox4.Value = "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, count As Long, K As Long
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim countT As Date 'declared the variable here
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        arrData = rng.Value
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng.Columns(1), CStr(ComboBox2.Value), rng.Columns(2), ComboBox1.Value, rng.Columns(7), ComboBox3.Value, rng.Columns(10), ComboBox4.Value)
        ReDim arrList(1 To count + 1, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrList(1, j) = arrData(1, j) 'header
        Next
        K = 1
        countT = 0 ' ** Add
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value And _
                arrData(i, 1) = CStr(ComboBox2.Value) And _
                arrData(i, 7) = ComboBox3.Value And _
                arrData(i, 10) = ComboBox4.Value Then
                K = K + 1
                ' countT = 0 ' ** Remove
                ' For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2) ' ** Remove
                countT = countT + arrData(i, 5) 'trying to get their total sum
                arrList(K, 5) = Format(arrData(i, 5), "hh:mm:ss")
                ' Next ' ** Remove
                ' Label1.Caption = Format(CDate(countT), "hh:mm:ss") ' ** Remove
            End If
        Next
        Me.Label1.Caption = Format(CDate(countT), "hh:mm:ss") 'show total sum in this label in the form of hh:mm:ss
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "0,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = arrList
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: let me try brb....

Comment: Updated with `how 0:03:00 is determined`.